# BLE characteristic write value occasionally jumps to a random value

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Using Core Bluetooth with Swift 3, I use `CBPeripheral.writeValue()` to write a characteristic to the Central, and I do this when the value of a `UISlider` changes. I was noticing that, even when dragging the slider slowly, occasionally a jump in value would be seen on the Central. I thought perhaps some over-the-air corruption was occurring, so I changed the characteristic to write the same value three times. Now, only if all the values received by the Central match will it act on them. Here's the current code:

```
@IBAction func slideValChanged(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    let sliderVal = UInt8(sender.value.rounded(FloatingPointRoundingRule.down))
    if (sliderVal != self.sliderVal)
    {
        self.sliderVal = sliderVal
        self.bytes.removeAll()
        self.bytes = [self.sliderVal, self.sliderVal, self.sliderVal]
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async
        {
            self.data = Data(bytes: self.bytes)
            self.peripheral.writeValue(self.data, for: self.writeCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            print("Write values sent:", self.bytes[0], self.bytes[1], self.bytes[2])
        }
    }
}
```

Even with this, I still see the value jump, and not to anything particular. The `print()` statement always prints the same (and correct) number three times. Similarly, on the Central, when the value jumps, I receive three equal but incorrect values. How can this be? All I can think is that something in Core Bluetooth is changing the value before it is put on air, but I'm not sure, and I don't know where to focus my attention.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why do you write `self.data as Data` if `self.data`  (apparently) already has the type `Data` ?

Comment: Just some extraneous code. I've removed and retested. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse, even slow movement of your slider will send to many packets.
When you write to the writeCharacteristic command you need to wait for a callback before calling writeCharacteristic again. The callback will indicate that your data has been buffered in the Central BLE-stack and the stack is ready to receive additional data. Without this Your data can be corrupted or even lose your connection.